# how do use the facebook connect api's with the iphone?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am currently developing an iphone application which is nearing completion but i want to add in the functionality to be able to connect with facebook. I can grasp the basic functionality of this such as connecting and posting status updates and feeds but id like to be able to interact with friends and events within facebook, much like the flixster movies app where you can view friends ratings etc... Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I am fairly new to this all so i need as much help as possible please.

Thanks

James

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk/

Download this project - it has a facebook connect iphone sdk as well as some example code to walk you through.

Next take a look at developer.facebook.com and go through the apis. You will find apis here to do what you want to do using your iphone app.